# Does CREATE TABLE AS lock the table?

Tags: postgresql, locking, table

In Postgres, does this query lock `films` for reads and/or writes?

```sql
CREATE TABLE films2 AS
  TABLE films;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not create a read or write lock on films table as this creates ACCESS SHARE LOCK;

to test this  open two sessions

in session one  run this command

```
  begin;
  create table films2 as 
     table films;
```

then in the second session run this command

```
Select * from films;
Update films set something = 0
```

If you need to lock films table you have to issue a Lock like so

```
begin ;
  Lock table films in exclusive mode;
  create table films2 as 
     table films;
commit;
```

this will block the table from updates but not reads...

NOTE  Access Share Locks block any transaction that try to acquire an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE locks such as DROP Films etc...

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thank you for reversing

Comment: Well, it is necessary to admit a mistake. I read the question sloppily and did not see that OP specifically asked for locks that would block read and write.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  I modified the answer to call the specifics,  I should have spelled out specifically what Postgres is doing, and that read blocks only occur on Access Exclusive events